# Issue with bulma cdn 0.8.0 not recognizing spacing helper

Tags: html, css, cdn, bulma

Just went back to an older project I started awhile ago with bulma. But for some reason or another the 0.8.0 cdn isn't being imported/recognized correctly by the spacing classes. The code I had was

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.8.0/css/bulma.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fontawesome/5.10.1/css/all.css">

<section class="section">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="title has-text-centered mt-6">Some text</h1>
            ...
            ...
        </div>
</section>
```

but the title text kept getting cut off by the navbar as you can see from the screenshot

[image]

But when I update to newer cdn (0.9.0) like so

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.0/css/bulma.min.css">
```

it recognizes the spacing class/helper? Does/has anyone had this issue before? I only changed one character (8 to 9) to fix it & I'm concerned about what may happen in the future. I can't remember the documentation for 0.8.0 but I think `mt-6` should be the same in both versions...

[image]

Comment: Seems like an EZ fix. Just use the newest version. I've used Bulma on a few projects and have not had any major issues with stuff breaking l8r on. ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

I believe bulma Spacing helpers was an npm extension before version 9.
now and directly integrate into version 9